# Unsure of Exception for JSON - Java

Tags: java, json, exception

My program takes a JSON array of numbers and from it makes an int array in Java. 
I need to be able to print a message saying the JSON input is messed up if there is a word instead of a number or if there is a comma with no number after it.
I'm new to using JSON and exceptions in Java. 
How do I handle these cases?

```
  try
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < inArray.size(); i++)
    {
     tempArray[i] = inArray.getInt(i);
    }

    JsonArrayBuilder outArrayBuilder = Json.createArrayBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < inArray.size(); i++) 
    { 
      outArrayBuilder.add(tempArray[i]); 
    }

    out.println("{ \"outList\" : " + outArrayBuilder.build().toString() + " }");
  }
  catch (???)
  {
    out.println("{ \"message\" : \"Malformed JSON\" }");
  }
```

Obviously this isn't all of my code, but the rest isn't important.

Comment: Show us your code, and we can try to point in the right direction.

Comment: @cricket_007 I know the try-catch part, but not what exception

Comment: @Steve101 I added some of my code, the relevant stuff

Comment: You can read the API documentation or let the IDE tell you exactly what you need to catch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use try and catch you are, at a simple level, trying to do something and catching the error if it goes wrong.

In the example you have given you appear to be unsure of what to catch; you need to purely catch the exception that is being generated. This can be the base `Exception e`, which is a global catch all but generally it is best to catch exceptions at a granular level.

You can read more about exceptions here; https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/

Comment: I definitely need to learn more about all of this, but this is important for a deadline. Thank you for your help!